# Sending intent from child activity to the main activity based on if child activity *Not result-based

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a main activity and 6 child activities.  I have a condition where 5 of the 6 child activities can be accessed at any time, but the button that opens the 6th child activity will only become clickable once the other 5 child activities have been opened.
To do so I made a boolean array of 5 in the main activity.  When one of the 5 always clickable buttons are clicked, its associated boolean variable becomes true.  In order to prevent it from returning to false when a new activity is opened, I'm sending the array from the main activity to the child activity and back using Intents.  I have no difficulty sending the array from the main to the child, but I can't send it from child to main. The following is the relevant code;

```
//MAIN ACTIVITY
//onClick method
public void openFirst(View view){
    opened[0] = true;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstChild.class);
    intent.putExtra("OpenIntent", opened);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//CHILD ACTIVITY
//onCreate method
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    open = getIntent().getBooleanArrayExtra("OpenIntent");
    //rest of oncreate method
}
//invoked by pressing back arrow 
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("OpenIntent",open);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
//MAIN ACTIVITY
//onCreate method
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    opened = getIntent().getBooleanArrayExtra("OpenIntent")
    //rest of onCreate method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong. If you want data, then you can store it in `SharedPreference` and access from there or you can use `startActivityForResult()` in `MainActivity` while starting the childActivity and `onBackPress()` inside ChildActivity use `setResult()` for retrieving the data in `onActivityResult()`.